# Enhancing the resolution of an image

Tags: image, machine-learning, image-processing, deep-learning, computer-vision

I have images that are having very low quality and these images I have to use for person identification but with this quality it's difficult to detect. I want to enhance the quality of the images using deep learning/machine learning techniques. I have studied about SRCNN, perceptual Loss, SRResNet, SRGAN but most of the super image resolution techniques require original images for improving the quality of the images. So my question is there any deep learning techniques that can be used for the improving the quality of the images without using the original images.

[image: image with low quality]

Comment: No, you can't create quality from nowhere - else we'd all use $5 cameras and increase the quality magically to that of a Hasselblad or Nikon.

Comment: I got your point but I am not talking about making an image in HD quality but increase the quality little bit.

Comment: Would be criminal to use such cr*p for person identification.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you dont need to re-train deep learning model like SRGAN etc. for enhancing quality of images you can use pretrained model.

Below is the result obtained from running model on your image, please noted these are general model and result will be different based on image in question

[image]

Here another example for different low resolution image, in this difference will be visible

[image]

If you are looking for practical implementation of super resolution using pretrained model in OpenCV, have a look at below notebook also video describing details.

https://github.com/pankajr141/experiments/blob/master/Reasoning/ComputerVision/super_resolution_enhancing_image_quality_using_pretrained_models.ipynb

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JrWIYWO4bac&list=UUplf_LWNn0a9ubnKCZ-95YQ&index=4

Below is a sample code describing opencv library details

```
model_pretrained = cv2.dnn_superres.DnnSuperResImpl_create()

# setting up the model initialization
model_pretrained.readModel(filemodel_filepath)
model_pretrained.setModel(modelname, scale)

# prediction or upscaling
img_upscaled = model_pretrained.upsample(img_small)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try applying a sharpening kernel

Before `->` After

[image]
[image]

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

image = cv2.imread('1.jpg')
sharpen_kernel = np.array([[-1,-1,-1], [-1,9,-1], [-1,-1,-1]])
sharpen = cv2.filter2D(image, -1, sharpen_kernel)

cv2.imshow('sharpen', sharpen)
cv2.waitKey()
```